# Adding components to a JFrame

Tags: java, jcomponent

In the below program I have created a button that when clicked should show another jframe with added components. But when I click on this button it does not show any components only a blank jframe appears with title.
What's my problem can anyone explain it?

---

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            JFrame f1 = new JFrame();
            f1.setVisible(true);
            f1.setSize(800, 700);
            f1.setTitle("Calc");
            f1.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            JTextField t1 = new JTextField(10);
            JTextField t2 = new JTextField(10);
            JTextField t3 = new JTextField(10);

            JButton b1 = new JButton("1");
            JButton b2 = new JButton("2");
            JButton b3 = new JButton("3");
            JButton b4 = new JButton("4");
            JButton b5 = new JButton("5");
            JButton b6 = new JButton("6");
            JButton b7 = new JButton("7");
            JButton b8 = new JButton("8");
            JButton b9 = new JButton("9");
            JButton b10 = new JButton("0");
            JButton b11 = new JButton("Add");
            JButton b12 = new JButton("Sub");
            JButton b13 = new JButton("Mul");
            JButton b14 = new JButton("Div");
            JButton b15 = new JButton("=");
            JButton b16 = new JButton("CLR");

            f.getContentPane().add(t1);
            f.getContentPane().add(t2);
            f.getContentPane().add(t3);

            f.getContentPane().add(b1);
            f.getContentPane().add(b2);
            f.getContentPane().add(b3);
            f.getContentPane().add(b4);
            f.getContentPane().add(b5);
            f.getContentPane().add(b6);
            f.getContentPane().add(b7);
            f.getContentPane().add(b8);
            f.getContentPane().add(b9);
            f.getContentPane().add(b10);
            f.getContentPane().add(b11);
            f.getContentPane().add(b12);
            f.getContentPane().add(b13);
            f.getContentPane().add(b14);
            f.getContentPane().add(b15);
            f.getContentPane().add(b16);

    }
});
```

Comment: I do not know what `f` is, but you are adding the content to it, instead of the newly created `f1` frame...

Comment: Did you mean adding the buttons to `f1` ? Do you set `f1` to visible anywhere ?  Post [mcve] and save us the need to guess

Answer (score 1):

Possibly typo error in your case as address by the other answers.

1. Use `f1` instead of `f`
2. Move the line `f1.setVisible(true);` below to the bottom when you are done with adding buttons to it, i.e. `f1.getContentPane().add(b16);`

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have refrenced a JFrame as `f1` and you are adding component to `f` so it will not add anything to your frame so,
 try using to add in `f1` instead of `f`  and also move `f1.setVisible(true);` below after adding every component to`f1` as i have shown below

```
    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

  @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        JFrame f1 = new JFrame();

        f1.setSize(800, 700);
        f1.setTitle("Calc");
        f1.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JTextField t1 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField t2 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField t3 = new JTextField(10);

        JButton b1 = new JButton("1");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("2");
        JButton b3 = new JButton("3");
        JButton b4 = new JButton("4");
        JButton b5 = new JButton("5");
        JButton b6 = new JButton("6");
        JButton b7 = new JButton("7");
        JButton b8 = new JButton("8");
        JButton b9 = new JButton("9");
        JButton b10 = new JButton("0");
        JButton b11 = new JButton("Add");
        JButton b12 = new JButton("Sub");
        JButton b13 = new JButton("Mul");
        JButton b14 = new JButton("Div");
        JButton b15 = new JButton("=");
        JButton b16 = new JButton("CLR");

        f1.getContentPane().add(t1);
        f1.getContentPane().add(t2);
        f1.getContentPane().add(t3);

        f1.getContentPane().add(b1);
        f1.getContentPane().add(b2);
        f1.getContentPane().add(b3);
        f1.getContentPane().add(b4);
        f1.getContentPane().add(b5);
        f1.getContentPane().add(b6);
        f1.getContentPane().add(b7);
        f1.getContentPane().add(b8);
        f1.getContentPane().add(b9);
        f1.getContentPane().add(b10);
        f1.getContentPane().add(b11);
        f1.getContentPane().add(b12);
        f1.getContentPane().add(b13);
        f1.getContentPane().add(b14);
        f1.getContentPane().add(b15);
        f1.getContentPane().add(b16);
         f1.setVisible(true);
    }
   });
```